# Create logical ordered queue list from percentage value

Tags: math, percentage

This is math task. I need to create an order list (or queue list) from x values - everyone is percent and sum of all of them is 100. I want logical order of these values. Let see this:

```
a = 50,
b = 25,
c = 15,
d = 10
```

The greatest common divisor of these numbers is 5, so the queue should has length 100/5 = 20. And the result should look like this (or very similar):

```
a, b, a, b, a, c, a, b, a, d, a, c, a, b, a, c, a, b, a, d
```

I'm looking for formula how to this order. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is that order related to gcd? I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you'd like to distribute each letter as uniformly as possible throughout the array or string. The preliminary step of finding the greatest common divisor and dividing the numbers 50,25,15,10 by it is straightforward. Once this is done, you get the number of times each letter must appear. Then the algorithm can be: beginning with the empty string, add the "most underrepresented" letter, repeat. I define "most underrepresented" as the one with the maximal difference of (desired proportion) - (actual proportion so far).

Here is this algorithm implemented in Python.

```
count = {'a': 10, 'b': 5, 'c': 3, 'd': 2}
length = sum(count.values())
str = ''
while len(str) < length:
    deficit = {}
    for char in count:
        deficit[char] = count[char]/length - (str.count(char)/len(str) if str else 0)
    str += max(deficit, key=deficit.get)
print(str)
```

The output is abcadabacabadabacaba. Split by letter to show the distribution:

```
a..a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a
.b....b...b...b...b.
..c.....c.......c...
....d.......d.......
```